# How to access powershell script's exit code in groovy

Tags: powershell, groovy

I have a powershell script as follows:

```
Write-Output "Hello"
Start-Sleep -s 2
exit 1
```

I want to access the exit code that the powershell script has set into my groovy file. Currently I have my groovy file as follows:

```
println "Hello World!"

smokeTestELB()

def smokeTestELB(){
    println "before call"

    def powerShellCommand = '.\\power.ps1'
    def shellCommand = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command \"${powerShellCommand}\""
    def process = shellCommand.execute()
    process.waitFor()

    println process.outputStream

    println "after call"
}

println "This is after powershell script has executed!"
```

However, when I try to access and print `process.outputStream`, I do not get the expected exit code.

My sample output is as follows:

[image]

Not sure how to access the exit code from powershell into my groovy script. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer after little more googeling ... Thanks to the post written here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/vaibhav/not-as-easy-as-we-thought-powershell-from-java-runtime

Basically, you have to use `'println process.exitValue()'` and it would print out the exit code.

Please note that the word `process` is specific to this solution.

Comment: The link isn't working anymore